# Adding a second Label to a matplotlib graph created with Seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I have some code that I use to make a graph based on some data that was previously imported. At the moment, the code will make a graph with a legend for the data itself, but I'm trying to add a second legend that displays the values for N and r in it (and nothing else). I would like to preferably modify existing code as little as possible. Most online help details how to add a second legend that signals existing Data being shown in the graph, but never numbers that are generated technically outside.

```
import seaborn as sns

N = len(alldata)
print(N)
r = np.corrcoef(WL_array, BUFKIT_array)
r = r[0][1]
print(r)

sns.set_theme(style="white")
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
sns.scatterplot(x="Radiosonde Freezing Level Height (m)", y="BUFKIT Freezing Level Height (m)", hue="Season",
            sizes=40, alpha=1, palette="muted", data=data, ax=ax).set(title = "Scatter Radiosonde vs. BUFKIT")

plt.xlim(1000,6000)
plt.ylim(1000,6000)
plt.plot(np.arange(min(WL_array), max(WL_array)), np.arange(min(WL_array), max(WL_array)), '--', dashes = (5,10), color = 'darkgray', label = '1:1 line')
```

[here is a picture of the graph that is generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1uis.png)
That graph has a single Legend with the information in the graph, and I'd like to add a second one with the other values